# Why the Image view inside the item of a list view disappears when i scroll?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, visibility

I am having a list view inside a tabs fragments,
Now inside the list view i am having two views one view is already at gone visibility.when i scroll the list view both the view disappears.I am handling with the holders,but still I am facing the issue.

here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_maino"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="76dp" 
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

     <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_coloro"
            android:layout_width="6dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:background="@color/green"
             >
        </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_texto"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
           android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_subtitleo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Header" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tv_subo"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textColor="@color/addr_col"
             android:textSize="12sp"
             android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
             android:text="subtext subtext subtext subtext subtext subtexts ubtexts subtexts" />

    </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_costo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="AED 12200" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_addo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_costo"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"

             >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_minuso"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/minus_selector" 
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_numbero"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="0" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_pluso"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/plus_selector" />

        </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_unavailo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_costo"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
             android:visibility="gone"
             >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_unavailo"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/addr_col"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="@string/c_unavail" />


        </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.only_pro_items, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();

          holder.rl_main=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl_maino);
          holder.rl_color=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl_coloro);
          holder.ll_unavail=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_unavailo); 
          holder.ll_text=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_texto);
          holder.ll_add=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_addo);
          holder.tv_subtitle=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subtitleo);
          holder.tv_sub=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subo);
          holder.tv_cost=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_costo);
          holder.tv_number=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_numbero);
          holder.tv_unavail=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_unavailo);
          holder.iv_minus=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_minuso);
          holder.iv_plus=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_pluso);

          convertView.setTag(holder);

      } else {
          Log.d("ttt", "3");
          holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

      }

    holder.tv_subtitle.setTypeface(gotham_book);
    holder.tv_sub.setTypeface(gotham_light);
    holder.tv_cost.setTypeface(gotham_book);
    holder.tv_number.setTypeface(gotham_book);
    holder.tv_unavail.setTypeface(gotham_light);

    final Model_OnlyProduct model=arr_model.get(position);
    holder.tv_subtitle.setText(model.getTv_name());
    holder.tv_sub.setText(model.getTv_sub_name());

     final int price[]={0};

    if (!model.getTv_price().matches("")) {
        holder.tv_cost.setText(Constants.currency+model.getTv_price());
        price[0]=Integer.parseInt(model.getTv_price());
    } else {
        holder.tv_cost.setText("From "+Constants.currency+model.getFrom_price());
        price[0]=Integer.parseInt(model.getFrom_price());
    }




   if (model.getInStock().matches("In Stock")) {

      holder.ll_unavail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {

        holder.ll_unavail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.ll_add.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


  String food_class=model.getRl_color();

   switch (food_class) {
    case "Veg":
        holder.rl_color.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.veg_green));
    break;
    case "Non Veg":
        holder.rl_color.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.non_red));
    break;

    case "Egg":
        holder.rl_color.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.egg_yellow));
    break;

    case "":
        holder.rl_color.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    break;    

    }


   final int[] count={0};
   if (count[0]==0) {
    holder.tv_number.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       }

   holder.iv_plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (count[0]>=0&&count[0]!=99) {
                Log.d("qqq", "ar1r="+model.getCustom_status());
                if (model.getCustom_status().matches("1")) {

                    if (model.getCustom_type().matches("Combo")) {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(activity, Combo.class);
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_ID, String.valueOf(model.getId()));
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_NAME,model.getTv_name());
                        if (!model.getTv_price().matches("")) {
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_TYPE, "price");
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_PRICE, model.getTv_price());
                        } else {
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_TYPE, "from");
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_PRICE, model.getFrom_price());
                        }

                        intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_COUNT,  String.valueOf(count[0]));
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_SUBTEXT, model.getTv_sub_name());
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_FROM, "menu");
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.VIEW_INDEX, ""+model.getView_index());
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                        activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.move_up, R.anim.stay);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(activity, Toppings.class);
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_ID, String.valueOf(model.getId()));
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_NAME,model.getTv_name());
                        if (!model.getTv_price().matches("")) {
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_TYPE, "price");
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_PRICE, model.getTv_price());
                        } else {
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_TYPE, "from");
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_PRICE, model.getFrom_price());
                        }

                        intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_COUNT,  String.valueOf(count[0]));
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_SUBTEXT, model.getTv_sub_name());
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.ITEM_FROM, "menu");
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                        activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.move_up, R.anim.stay);
                    }
                }else
                {

                holder.tv_number.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                count[0]++;
                Constants.cart_count++;

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        holder.tv_number.setText(String.valueOf(count[0]));
                        FragmentMenu.tv_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        FragmentMenu.tv_count.setText(String.valueOf(Constants.cart_count));

                        int total=price[0];
                        Constants.cart_amount+=total;
                        FragmentMenu.tv_cart_money.setText(Constants.currency+Constants.cart_amount);
                    }
                });
                Constants.count++;
                String id=String.valueOf(Constants.count);
                HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(Constants.ITEM_ID, String.valueOf(model.getId()));
                map.put(Constants.ITEM_NAME, model.getTv_name());


                    map.put(Constants.ITEM_PRICE, model.getTv_price());



                map.put(Constants.ITEM_PRICE, model.getTv_price());
                map.put(Constants.ITEM_COUNT, String.valueOf(count[0]));
                map.put(Constants.ID, id);


                if (Constants.arr_global.size()>0) {
                    int count=Constants.arr_global.size();
                    boolean yettop=false;
                    int qwer=0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map2=Constants.arr_global.get(i);
                        String item_id=map2.get(Constants.ITEM_ID);
                        if (item_id.matches(String.valueOf(model.getId()))) {
                            yettop=true;
                            qwer=i;
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            yettop=false;
                        }
                    }

                    if (yettop) {
                        Constants.arr_global.remove(qwer);
                        Constants.arr_global.add(map);
                    } else {
                        Constants.arr_global.add(map);
                    }
                }else {
                    Constants.arr_global.add(map);
                }

            }

        }
        }
    });

    return convertView;

}
```

issue is:

```
if (model.getInStock().matches("In Stock")) {

      holder.ll_unavail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {

        holder.ll_unavail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.ll_add.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

in this loop the next item visibility get changes..

Comment: your layout doesnt contain any button...

Comment: my mistake image view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this condition and check

```
 if (model.getInStock().matches("In Stock")) {
holder.ll_add.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      holder.ll_unavail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {

        holder.ll_unavail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.ll_add.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: welcome also you have to do same with  holder.tv_number i think